# How to define a custom type of an Arrayreference of Ints in Perl 6?

Tags: validation, raku

How to define a custom type of an Array-Reference of Ints in Perl 6? I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
subset Array_of_Int of Array where *.all ~~ Int;
```

---

```
my $n = My::Class.new( option => < 22 3 4 5 > );

# Type check failed in assignment to $!option; expected My::Class::Array_of_Int but got List in block <unit> at ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In My::Class:

```
has Int @.option;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why to do this, most perl6 programmers with declare subset for array element but not for array itself. Rakudo decides to create `List` instead of `Array` -> the same trap comes when using `Rat` type instead of `Num`. Anyway it is possible. Subset is not fully qualified type (it is not possible to instance it). You have to create an array explicitly `$aoi = Array[Int].new(1,2,3,4,5,6)`.

```
> subset AoI of Array of Int
> my AoI $aoi;
> $aoi = Array[Int].new    
> $aoi.append(1,2,3,4)
  [1 2 3 4]
> $aoi.append("mystr")
Type check failed in assignment to ; expected Int but got Str
in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

Comment: I need only `has Int @.option` , but I didn't know that before.